# Recurring Donation Email Issues with iATS payment processor

Tags: email, receipts, recurring-contributions

I'm trying to get our recurring donations up and running and I've run into some difficulties. When an admin sets up a recurring donation, Civi send the receipt for the first donation in the series just right, however it doesn't include the recurring donation management information. If we set up a donation through the online form, the series is created, and it works, but no email is sent. Any future processed donations don't send an email either. Email is working through Civi for everything else. Here are the site details:

WordPress 4.2.1
CiviCRM 4.5.8
Payment Processor: iATS using the iATS extension [(CiviCRM iATS Payment Extension)](https://civicrm.org/extensions/iats-payments))
Using Mandrill as SMTP sending agent

Answer (score 4):

It's because iATS does not do IPNs. It's not specific to iATS (it affects all processors that don't do IPNs - and that number has been growing).

Comment: There's an open issue here: https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm/issues/65 which might fix things but hasn't been tested yet. I hope we can look at it in the next month, it would require you to be using the latest versions of 4.4 or 4.6.