# Expected information for iATS recurring contributions?

Tags: civicontribute, iats

CiviCRM 4.7.13, iATS extension 1.5.3.  Is this the information I should expect to see in the contribution record, or should a payment be referenced?  [image]  In particular, I'm wondering about the "no payments found" line.  I am aware of the issue affecting the creation of civicrm_financial_item records ([Recurring iATS contributions not creating civicrm_finanical_item records](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14469/recurring-iats-contributions-not-creating-civicrm-finanical-item-records) ) and I would anticipate they will need to update the extension sooner rather than later, but I'm not clear on what I *should* be seeing here.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that 1.5.3 (see XML file) is not compatible with CiviCRM 4.7.x; you must upgrade to the 1.6.x series.

PS - the issue you're referencing is re: 4.6 (completetransaction API does not create Financial transactions); for the 4.7 version we are able to use repeattransaction API - which does create Financial transactions.

PS2 - after updating to the 1.6.x you will be seeing payment information there (CiviCRM core recently has also added last 4digits of cc - in addition to $amount, financial type(s) payment instrument id.

Comment: You're welcome - any time!